# InstallUtill of GCC compiled .exe receiving System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: windows-services, service, installutil, badimageformatexception

I am trying to use a GCC compiled .exe as a service in windows. From what I have researched I should do:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe [program name]
```

Although when I try to do this I receive a message as such:

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Setup4\Setup4\Service.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..
```

I have a feeling that this is due to the fact that the program was compiled using GCC and did use some .a files to compile.

From what I see **System.BadImageFormatException** is usually caused by some sort of bad manifest. Would someone be able to help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InstallUtil` is used to install .Net applications as services. Unless GCC can produce managed assemblies, you should be using `sc.exe` instead to create a Windows service entry for your application.